# Haskell array conditions confusion

Tags: haskell

How do I output city names that had temps higher than 5 on the 4th day (4th index)? I can't figure out the conditions. I've tried a couple of things, but nothing worked. I can get the index of item 5, but I don't know how to apply that to the array of items. I can't just do loops like I would in Java.

```
data City = City { cityName :: String
                 , temperature :: [Double] 
                 }

city1 = City {cityName = "city1", temperature = [4.50,6.50,5.0,6.48,8.54]}
city2 = City {cityName = "city2", temperature = [6.35,5.12,3.21,3.25,4.56]}
city3 = City {cityName = "city3", temperature = [7.3,5.32,4.4,4.6]}

cities :: [City]
cities = [city1,city2,city3]

getTemperatures (City _ _ temperature) = temperature

test :: City -> Double 
test x = (getTemperatures x)!!5
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a homework service. What have you tried? What happened? Show us your code so far, and we can suggest solutions to a specific problem.

Comment: Sorry @PaulJohnson i realise i missed stuff, and this isnt homework this is me tyring to understand concepts, this should be easy but im not understanding iterations in haskell as it doesnt work like anything ive used before.

Comment: You need the `filter` function. In Haskell we don't iterate, we use recursion. Try doing it with `filter`. Then try doing it with recursion and pattern matching on a list of cities. Then take a look at the definition of `filter` and see if enlightenment follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `map` (I am using 3rd index (0-base) here):

```py
main = print $ map cityName $ filter ((>5) . (!!3) . temperature) cities -- ["city1"]

data City = City { cityName :: String, temperature :: [Double] }

city1 = City {cityName = "city1", temperature = [4.50,6.50,5.0,6.48,8.54]}
city2 = City {cityName = "city2", temperature = [6.35,5.12,3.21,3.25,4.56]}
city3 = City {cityName = "city3", temperature = [7.3,5.32,4.4,4.6]}

cities :: [City]
cities = [city1,city2,city3]
```

The `filter` filters (from the list `cities`) elements by taking the temperature part (`temperature`), take the third element (`!!3`), and then compare it with 5 (`>5`).

The `map`, given the output from `filter`, then takes the name part (`cityName`). Finally, `print` prints the list of city names.